# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasOwnProperty') on Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

What causes this error? Work perfectly on local, yet in server, when I click on the button that triggers the next page this shows up and broken the load. It's a core error I can't find what is caused by.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasOwnProperty')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasOwnProperty')
    at v (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:120:17)
    at Tg (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:19748:35)
    at t.get (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:20452:16)
    at ym (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:20823:45)
    at gm (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:20703:32)
    at fm (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:20574:20)
    at Wm (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:21800:36)
    at Hm (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:21714:5)
    at Object.sy [as createRootView] (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:22226:12)
    at e.create (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:20053:29)
    at F (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:809:31)
    at F (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:775:17)
    at zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:858:17
    at t.invokeTask (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:421:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:16126:33)
    at t.invokeTask (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:420:36)
    at e.runTask (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:188:47)
    at g (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:595:35)
    at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:500:21)
    at m (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1517:14)
```

Comment: It will be quite hard to tell without some more context. Maybe try supply the code for the button you're clicking.

Comment: It's a simply this.router.navigate([route.path], { skipLocationChange: true});
The route.path is correct I debugged it

Comment: It's error because you are trying to access a property but that's not defined or may be null.